# Does 'creating' a new record override existing ones with same key?

Tags: django

The first code below both creates (if it doesn't exist yet) and override (if it exists) record in db. It's convenient. I would like to know if this creates problem in the DB.

I reviewed the table records and it doesn't create duplicates.

```
record = Foo(key='123', value='Hello)
record.save()
```

or

```
try:
  foo_q = Foo.objects.get(key='123')
  foo_q.value = 'Hello'
  foo_q.save()
except:
  record = Foo(key='123', value='Hello)
  record.save()
```

It works but is it safe to continue using or should I query if it exists and update the model.

Comment: It should be fine, but you can use [update_or_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create) method or exists/update methods if its convenient to you.

Comment: I see someone voted to close this question as "primarily opinion-based". I'd like this person to reconsider their vote - there are huge differences between those two snippets, and neither are safe, so it's definitly a question that has a clear, technical answer.

Comment: What do you mean by "safe" or "creates a problem"? What is your concern, specifically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second example is more safe. 
You can use `update_or_create` method. If you want to override value if exist with `key`

```
foo, created = Foo.objects.update_or_create(
        key='123', defaults={"value": "Hello"}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

> The first code below both creates (if it doesn't exist yet) and override (if it exists) record in db

Only if your model has an automatic primary_key field - if `key` was the primary key, this *would* actually override an existing record (Django uses the primary key to check out if it should do an insert or an update).

wrt/ the second snippet, it is definitly **not** safe: first, the bare except clause can hide other issues in the (too wide) try block - it should actually been written as

```
try:
  foo = Foo.objects.get(key='123')
except Foo.DoesNotExist:
  foo = Foo(key='123', value='Hello')
else:
  foo.value = 'Hello'

foo.save()
```

But even then, it doesn't properly handle possible race conditions. I can only second Nagesh Dhope's recommandation on using `update_or_create` instead, but mostly because it does handle race conditions as much as possible (it's not totally failsafe, but it usually works as expected).

IOW, what you want is:

```
foo, created = Foo.objects.update_or_create(key=123, defaults={"value":"hello"})
```